# How to make Dynamic URL for Browser and Mobile Application - for Customer Confirmation mail URL?

Tags: magento2, api, redirect-url

Magento 2 gives us the ability to take more control of the customer account creation process.

There is a special configuration setting located in

> Admin under Stores → Configuration → Customers → Customer Configuration
>   → Create New Account Options named Require Emails Confirmation
>   (Yes/No)

I am receiving the mail and everything's works fine, But my concern is I have **Mobile Application** too for my Magento project.

And In **email confirmation button** I have URL like this

```
https://<magento.host>/customer/account/confirm/?id=123&key=b686b138f5ec5fe5ff7610b7527a9b4b
```

- Now, this URL is directly opens in the the browser even if customer has
  **Installed** the **Application**.

> Now, How can I make **Dynamic URL** for this specific functionality, If
>   user have Installed the application then It automatically opens in
>   **Mobile Application** and if user doesn't have the application then opens in
>   Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **[Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links)**. This is useful if you're creating promo links to share on social media. This way you can select a custom suffix and a name for the link in the Firebase console. You can track the performance of these **[Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/?authuser=0#implementation_paths)** in the Firebase console or via the Analytics REST API.

**API** `Method : POST`

```
https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=<Firebase project key>
```

**JSON > BODY > DATA**

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "https://<your_project>.page.link",
    "link": "https://<your_project>/customtab/custom/",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "<androidPackageName>"
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "<iosBundleId>"
    }
  }
}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "shortLink": "<shortLink by firebase>",
    "warning": [
        {
            "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
            "warningMessage": ""
        },
        {
            "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
            "warningMessage": ""
        }
    ],
    "previewLink": "<previewLink by firebase>"
}
```